# Running a 7v shift register from arduino 3.3v

Tags: arduino, led, voltage, display, shift-register

Im trying to learn some electronics, so im not that confident with some of these systems,

I recently bought a load of the [alphanumeric displays from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9933)  but foolishly read the data sheet for the red, then bought the blue. The difference is the operating voltage is 7v instead of 5v which is making things difficult.

I have also some shift registers, eg [74HC595](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/733) but they are rated only up to 6v, I have found other shift registers that take a higher voltage, such as the [cd4006b](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4006b.pdf), but they look like the clock and latch pins etc. also need to be at the higher voltage, so driving them from an Arduino is proving difficult.

Can someone give a simple solution or suggestion that im missing for keeping this simple?

Comment: The red display is 2 bucks... Easiest solution is to buy the correct display. I also wonder if Sparkfun would take a trade for the correct displays if you paid a restocking/shipping fee.

Comment: Majenko has the best answer.  I have used TPIC6C595 shift registers too (Note no constant current tho, 5V supply) because it is available in a DIP form factor.  74HC595 is not ideal because it will source current (not sink) and its max continuous current Vcc to GND is 70mA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a proper LED driver shift register. These are normally a constant current sink, and can accept up to around 30V usually.

One example is the STP16CP05

Comment: What is the context of the word "proper" here? What makes the 74HC595 improper?

Comment: "Proper" as in "Designed for the purpose".